# WCF service discovery issue, take much time to return results?

Tags: c#, wcf, service-discovery

I have a WCF server library and client[Winform], i launch the server using a self-host winform.

I want to let client to discover the active servers on LAN, in another way to get online servers IPAddresses in a list. i tried `DiscoveryClient` and `UdpDiscoveryEndpoint` and it worked this's the code :

**Client[Winform] :**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
        FindResponse findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IFileManager)));
        foreach (EndpointDiscoveryMetadata ep in findResponse.Endpoints)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(ep.Address.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Server[Winform] :**

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MainService));
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Start")
        {
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
            host.Open();
            button1.Text = "Stop";
        }
        else
        {
            host.Close();
            button1.Text = "Start";
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work like i expect it!

Why do i have to give a specific Criteria to ClientDiscovery ? i have many interfaces, i just need the host address, not the address of the interface!

it takes too much time [about 15-20s] to get the list, isn't suppose to be fast?

**UPDATE:**
I've developed a server discovery on TCP sockets before i used WCF, i used parallel threading that  try/catch to connect and loop over 255 IPAddresses ex: (192.168.1.X), i tried it on LAN 5 servers[PC], the result was so perfect and fast , i sat a timeout (3 sec) 
but on WCF i dont know how would i accomplish this !!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do i have to give a specific Criteria to ClientDiscovery ? i have many interfaces, i just need the host address, not the address of the interface!

That is the point of decoupling, the fact that all services that you need are on a single server is an implementation detail. That said, you *could* couple your client to your particular architecture, manually creating clients with the info from the MEX address received from the first result of the discovery process.

> it takes too much time [about 15-20s] to get the list, isn't suppose
>   to be fast?

No, discovery is not supposed to be fast if you are looking for multiple instances of a service: the default timeout is 20s. Now, if you need only 1 instance of that service (which is most of the time), then you could tell the client explicitly to stop after finding the first service, by setting the MaxResults property of FindCriteria to 1. That is way faster than waiting for the timeout.

For further information you can check this [excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335779.aspx).

**UPDATE**

You can set the timeout via the [FindCriteria.Duration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.findcriteria.duration.aspx) property.

**UPDATE 2**

All the information you can get about the service is through the MEX endpoint. You could use a MetadataExchangeClient with the MEX address you get from the discovery and make use of the info in the MetadataSet you get back (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730243.aspx, Retrieving Service Metadata), but I don't know for sure what kind of information you will get back since I never used it this way.

It depends on what you mean by status: WS-discovery has no concept of status that I'm aware of, either the service is there or not. Any other interpretation of this concept you have to implement yourself as an operation in your services.

Comment: i actually need to get all the online servers, why does it suppose to be slow!! what about NetSupport, PcAnyWhere, some multiplayer games .. i think it suppose to be fast, please take a look i've updated my question.

Comment: umm do you have any idea how would i let service discovery to return extra info, like computer name and status!

Comment: @MurHafSoz answer updated again :) please be aware that service discovery is not server discovery: all the additional work or structure to render it a server discovery mechanism you have to implement by yourself.

Comment: by status i mean a custom additional response that i add, like if this service already have a client connected, it returns BUSY.

Comment: @MurHafSoz then yes, you have to implement an operation for that, where you check if a client is already connected using your business definition of connected (for instance, last activity < `x` seconds).

Comment: thanks for helping :) , i think that should be a new question to know how to i add a custom operation.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `DiscoveryClient`'s `FindAsync()` method with the `FindProgressChanged` and `FindCompleted` events rather than the synchronous `Find()` method, you'll find that the `FindProgressChanged` event is fired as soon as the endpoint results come in, meaning you'll have access to them immediately instead of having to wait to the end of the search. You'll know the search is over when `FindCompleted` fires.

For me, it doesn't take more than a few seconds before all my network's clients have reported in through the `FindProgressChanged` event using this method.

Oh, and if you need to cancel your search for any reason (somebody closed your dialog in the middle of the search, for instance), then call the `DiscoveryClient`'s `CancelAsync()` method.

Comment: For me this answer actually answers the question. The accepted answer just says the OP is wrong without proper explanation. Discovery is fast and using the Sync methods is the reason for the delayed response.

Comment: @DavidRitchie Indeed. However, I answered this question almost 3 years after it was asked, and the accepted answer was already accepted at the time. A lot of people won't bother going back and change their accepted answers when a better one comes along, as they've long since had their original problem solved. It's okay, though, I tend to post my answers in an attempt to help people, not for the points. :)